# Projection of a hypercube along a long diagonal. What is this polytope called?

Tags: projection, polytopes, discrete-geometry

I was wondering what people call a certain type of shape. It is the shape formed by an orthogonal projection of a hypercube along one of its longest diagonals.

In other words, fill in the missing entries:

```
n-simplex : Triangle ->      Tetrahedon        ->  5-cell    ...    
 n-cube   :  Square  ->         Cube           -> Tesseract  ...  
   ?      :  Hexagon -> Rhomibic Dodecahedron  ->     ?      ...
```

IMPORTANT: I'm looking for the name of the class of shapes, not just the 4D analogue.

Comment: It seems to me your arrows should point in the opposite direction---from right to left.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The arrows represent the well known coolness ordering of polytopes, read "X -> Y" as "Y is cooler than X". I think I get your intuition, there are increasing freedoms the way I drew them. e.g. the tetrahedron uniquely specifies the triangle, but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is the **vertex-frist projection of a hypercube**. Apparently it seems that the 4d analogue has no special name.

You can read [this post](http://teamikaria.com/hddb/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1679) for more informations.

**Edit:** I computed the polytope. Read my [blog post](http://ongraphs.de/blog/2013/02/vertex-first-projection-of-hypercubes/) about it. Here is a teaser:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the blog post no longer works.

Answer (score 3):

I got here via A. Schulz's blog entry. As he says, you are looking for the projection of the $(d+1)$-dimensional hypercube (the $(d+1)$-cube for short) along a diagonal. But, actually, any generic projection of the $(d+1)$-cube will give (combinatorially) the same polytope. By "generic" I just mean that the direction of projection is not parallel to any coordinate hyperplane.

A different description is that your polytope is the zonotope obtained as the Minkowski sum of any set of $d+1$ generic vectors in $\mathbb R^d$, where generic means that no $d$ of them lie in a hyperplane.

Comment: Can you please add a link to A. Schultz's blog entry?

Comment: The blog at least seems to be [Aaron Schultz's](http://aschultz.us), but I could not find the specific post.

Comment: It is not Aaron, but André Schultz. I did not add the link since he put the link in his answer, above (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/261323/64942). Anyway, the link is: http://ongraphs.de/blog/2013/02/vertex-first-projection-of-hypercubes/

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance that you are looking for the name of a {3,4,3} regular convex polychoron? It is called [**24-cell** (or icositetrachoron, octaplex, octacube polyoctahedron)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-cell).

[image: Solid orthographic projections][image: Wireframe Schlegel diagrams (Perspective projection)]

24-cell can be derived as a **rectified 16-cell** (different from [16-cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-cell)).

[image: all kinds of 16-cells]

Other related polychrons (uniform, but not necessary regular and convex):

[image: polychrons you may find useful]

---

Or if you are looking for a {5,3,3} regular and convex 4D polytope, it is called [120-cell (or hecatonicosachoron)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/120-cell).

[image: Solid orthographic projections] [image: Wireframe Schlegel diagrams (Perspective projection)]

---

Here is a [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope_families) I found on Wikipedia that describes the polytope families. Hope you find it useful.

[image]

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking, sorry :( Possibly it is the dual (in some sense) of the 24-cell.

Comment: Also, I want the name of a whole class.

Answer (score 0):

The polytopes you describe are the duals of a family of [uniform polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polytope).
So, they are higher-dimensional analogues of the [Catalan solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_solid).

I have currently no better idea for how to describe these uniform polytope to you other than by their [Coxeter diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter%E2%80%93Dynkin_diagram#Application_with_uniform_polytopes):

$\qquad\qquad$[image]

They belong to the $A_d$-family of uniform polytopes, that is, they have (an extended version of) the symmetry group of the $d$-simplex.

According to a link posted by A. Schulz, these polytopes are also called *"cats-eye polytopes"*, which I think is pretty cool.