# 4d projection of 5-cube

Tags: geometry, polytopes

The vertex-first parallel projection of the tesseract into three-dimensional space has a rhombic dodecahedral envelope. What is the four-dimensional projection of the five-cube? By analogy, its envelope should be a four-dimensional polytope that dissects into 5 congruent "rhombic" tesseracts in two possible ways.  What's the name of this object?

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255112/name-this-polytope

Comment: @RaviFernando Thx, this is basically what I was asking